# Is Signal-R supported by NET MAUI?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, maui

I've used Signal-R in a Blazor Server app, but I don't see a way to implement it in .NET MAUI. Apparently this environment doesn't support Signal-R yet, but I might be wrong.

If it is, how do I declare an `IHubContext<XHub>` as a service in MauiProgram.cs?

Comment: it works in Forms, so I don't know why it wouldn't work in MAUI

Comment: Are you trying to run a Signal R Hub in Maui? I can't imagine that will go well. For example, Android isn't going to let you open up a socket. If on the other hand you are trying to run a client on Maui, I can't see any problems...

Comment: I have tried on windows and MacOs Desktop and works well. Haven't tried on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself (will do later this year), but according to this project: https://github.com/matt-goldman/maui-chat it should be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Signal R Works

Setup:

```
Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
```

In your viewmodel or Page add:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
```

Declare:
private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;

On Page or ViewModal creation/constructor:

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(HUB_URL).WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

        _hubConnection.On<YourModel>("YOUR_EVENT", (item) =>
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                // Do a thing
            });
        });
```

Initialise the connection when required:

```
// Start signalr to get updates
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var connected = _hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
                            if (!connected)
                            {
                                await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
                                await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync("Subscribe", YOUR_IDENTIFIER);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    });
                });
```

The url is something like:

```
SiteUrl + "hubs/Yourhub";
```

Where your site has something like:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<App.SignalR.Hubs.FilesHub>("hubs/Yourhub");

            });
```